# AWS Amplify: Token is not from a supported provider of this identity pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, authentication, aws-amplify

I call this function on my app to allow for login through Facebook.

```
async fbSignIn(){
    const { type, token, expires } = await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync('454050215391261', {
        permissions: ['public_profile'],
    });
    if (type === 'success') {
        console.log(token);
        Auth.federatedSignIn('facebook', { token, expires_at: expires}, { name: 'USER_NAME' })
        .then(credentials => {
            console.log('get aws credentials', credentials);
            console.log("userProfile: ",JSON.stringify(userProfile));
            this.setState({ userProfile: userProfile});
            this.props.navigation.replace('Dashboard');
        }).catch(e => {
            console.log("ERROR:",e);
        });
    }
}
```

It properly opens the Facebook UI, but after entering my credentials I receive this error:

`NotAuthorizedException: Token is not from a supported provider of this identity pool.`

I have Facebook enabled as an identity provider for my user pool.
Any ideas how I can fix this?